# Load file_get_contents() full css and js another site

Tags: php

How to Clone the Entire Content from Other Sites For example:

1. My site: `www.example.com`
2. Site target: `www.google.com`

**In the scenario, I use:**

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
if(isset($url) && $url !== '') {
    echo file_get_contents($url);
}
```

The problem is, google sites load css and script with url path, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myscript.js"/>
```

The browser can not load it because my site does not have the css: `www.example.com/style.css`

Well, is there a possible way I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: Simply write a regex for fetching `href` and `src` values of link and script tag; Then file_get_Content the fetched uRL

Comment: seems like a great idea, but I do not know how to implement it

Comment: You could also try and insert a `base` element. (Although you’d have to check very carefully whether that might not create other issues.)

Comment: `preg_match_all('/<link.*?href="(.*?)"/ims', $html, $result)` with this you will get all css href

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple way to do it, tho its not perfect.

the best practice is to change `src` and `href` values via DOMDocument.

```
<?php 

 $content = file_get_contents($url); 
 $content = str_replace('src="/','src="'.$url.'/',$content);
 $content = str_replace('href="/','href="'.$url.'/',$content);
```